# PowerShell “.count” method causing incorrect processing

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am creating an array in PowerShell that doesn’t always contain data (sometimes it is empty).  I need to verify that the array contains data before trying to do anything to the array objects.  When I use the following code, everything works as expected:

```
$Array = @(“This”,”is”,”a”,”test”)
$Array | ForEach-Object {
If ($Array.Count -ge 1)
    {
    [string]$A = $_
    Write-Host $A
    }
}
```

Using the above code, I get the following output:

```
This
is
a
test
```

The above checks the ***.Count*** of the array each time it processes an object in the array (so it might check the count of the array a thousand times or more depending on the number of objects in the array).  What I want to do is to check the count of the array only once and before it starts processing the array objects.  However, the following code doesn’t provide the proper output:

```
$Array = @(“This”,”is”,”a”,”test”)
If ($Array.Count -ge 1)
{
$Array | ForEach-Object {
    {
    [string]$A = $_
    Write-Host $A
    }
}
}
```

I get the following output when I run the above code:

```
    [string]$A = $_
    Write-Host $A

    [string]$A = $_
    Write-Host $A

    [string]$A = $_
    Write-Host $A

    [string]$A = $_
    Write-Host $A
```

It doesn’t ***Write-Host*** the value of the ***$A*** variable like the previous code did but instead it prints out the actual PowerShell code itself.  All I did was move the ***.Count*** check so that it checks the count prior to the start of processing objects in the array.  Why do I get the above output when I move the array count check before the ***ForEach-Object*** statement?  Do I have to check the array count each time I process an object from the array?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing the reason why Powershell prints this for your second example

```
[string]$A = $_
Write-Host $A

[string]$A = $_
Write-Host $A
```

is because Powershell takes the double brace <kbd>{</kbd><kbd>{</kbd><kbd>}</kbd><kbd>}</kbd> as a string literal.

As for how to make this work, you should test the `$Array` before doing the for loop.

Here's what the code should look like :

```
$Array = @(“This”,”is”,”a”,”test”)
if($Array.Count -ge 1){
    foreach($A in $Array){
        Write-Host $A
    }
}
```

And as a one-liner(ish)

```
$Array = @(“This”,”is”,”a”,”test”) 
if($Array.Count -ge 1){ $Array| %{Write-Host $_}}
```

Comment: Sorry, I would put your name in but I'm having errors when entering my comments here - so I will just say Kudos - I have no idea why I was using double braces like that.  Formatting habit I guess.  I can't believe that I didn't see that one...It is working now...Thank you!!!

Comment: The thing in the curly brackets is a script block.